# Framer.js : how do you get the "previous" layer?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, framerjs

In Framer Studio (Coffeescript), whenever I click a layer, it's copied into another one (which is kind of a "checklist" layer if you will).
I'm trying to append a copied layer right below the previous one that has been clicked.
How would you do that ?
How do get the previous layer that has been clicked? Is it even possible?

Thank you very much for your help.

Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it could be by two ways.

First way is using `subLayers` and list of subLayers is relied on time being added.

```
bg = new BackgroundLayer
upper = new Layer
    width: 750, backgroundColor: "red", superLayer: bg
lower = new Layer
    width: 750, y: 100,     backgroundColor: "blue", superLayer: bg

lower.on Events.Click, (e, layer) ->
    parent = layer.superLayer
    index = parent.subLayers.indexOf layer
    prev = parent.subLayers[index-1] if ~index
    print prev
```

Another way is more simple. Store layers into array, and find within that.

```
layers = [new Layer, new Layer(x:150)]
layers[1].on Events.Click, (e, layer) ->
    index = layers.indexOf layer
    prev = layers[index-1] if ~index
    print prev
```